# Execution of grub-install/dev/sda failed. Now I can't boot either Windows 10 or Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I tried installing Ubuntu 22.04.1 on my PC which already had Windows 10 installed. I created a 30GB or so partition to install Ubuntu using logical partitions: one for the root, mounting in /, one for the /boot, a swap area and a EFI dedicated partition (I think the problem is in this one?)

After the installation an error popped up: "Execution of grub-install/dav/sda failed. This is a fatal error".

I then restarted the PC and what happens is that it automatically opens the BIOS. So I can't use either Ubuntu or Windows (I use my only hard disk as the first boot device)

Is there a way to fix this? My priority now is to rescue at least windows. I know all the data is still there: I can see it with gparted on Ubuntu (using it with "try Ubuntu" from the USB).

Comment: Was Windows not already installed in EFI mode? BTW your 30 gig is not enough. Root needs at least 40 gig itself. You do not need a swap partition now a days you use a swap file.

Comment: >Was Windows not already installed in EFI mode? How do I check this? Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fleF4qDtwDE and it worked. Now Ubuntu boots just fine. I just have to fix the fact that Windows 10 doesn't show up in the boot menu.

Comment: Have you tried grub the following command in a terminal? sudo update-grub ?

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: I will make it an answer so you can accept it. Done.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a dual boot setup you may at some time find yourself with not all the OS s being in the Grub menu.

This is actually a quite easy fix.

Open a terminal.

Type the following command and press enter.

sudo update-grub

You will be prompted for your password, enter it.

Reboot and you will see that the Grub menu now has both OS s to choose from.